# Get more screenlets not working

Tags: screenlets

Whenever I try to get more screenlets from the screenlets application it pops up with the browser telling me the screenlets.org is disabled.

Are screenlets deprecated? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Screenlet project is deprecated since 2008.

http://screenlets.org is dead.

You could want to look at [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/documentation.html), a program that allows you to write desklets, or at the [Cinnamon Desktop Environment](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/), a Linux Mint initiative based on Gnome that have a built-in screenlet management.