# This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources

Tags: updates, 15.10, system

This could be a duplicate, but nothing works. 
I'm updating this
[Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiNlK.png)

and get this error in sudo apt-get update

```
    W:GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any help is appreciated!

P.S. yes i use the main server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `apt-get update` does is refresh your package list from the remote [repositories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive) you have added, so that the package list don't need to be pulled every time you install anything. The error messages you're receiving are telling you that one (Or several) of your PPAs are returning 404 errors (In your case, screenlets-dev doesn't seem to have packages built for Wily Werewolf).

You're trying to upgrade your packages, so you should do `sudo apt-get upgrade` instead.

If you face any other issues, i'll be glad to help you out.

PS: [Screelets are deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/a/413997/435188).

Comment: lol thanks, i knew that it only updates the cache. i tried updating packages from Software Updater but it always comes w/ that error. For whatever reason using terminal worked w/ that command anyway, so thanks again (the error was "This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources")

Comment: wait, they are? is there an alternative

Comment: I believe there is [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/documentation.html), but i'm not sure if it is actively maintened.

PS: Not sure, i don't use either of them ;P